# How to mock HttpClientCertificate?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am trying to unit test an action filter I wrote. I want to mock the HttpClientCertificate but when I use MOQ I get exception. HttpClientCertificate doesnt have a public default constructor.

code:

```
//Stub HttpClientCertificate </br>
var certMock = new Mock<HttpClientCertificate>();
HttpClientCertificate clientCertificate = certMock.Object;
requestMock.Setup(b => b.ClientCertificate).Returns(clientCertificate);
certMock.Setup(b => b.Certificate).Returns(new Byte[] { });
```

Comment: Next time please format your code by using the `10101010` editor button or indenting it with 4 spaces :-)

Comment: Thanks Peter.I always get stuck with the formatting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most awkward case of creating unit testable systems in .NET. I invariable end up adding a layer of abstraction over the component that I can't mock. Normally this is required for classes with inaccessible constructors (like this case), non-virtual methods or extension methods.

Here is the pattern I use (which I think is [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)) and is similar to what MVC team has done with all the `RequestBase`/`ResponseBase` classes to make them unit  testable.

```
//Here is the original HttpClientCertificate class
//Not actual class, rather generated from metadata in Visual Studio

public class HttpClientCertificate : NameValueCollection {
    public byte[] BinaryIssuer { get; }
    public int CertEncoding { get; }
    //other methods
    //...
}

public class HttpClientCertificateBase {
    private HttpClientCertificate m_cert;

    public HttpClientCertificateBase(HttpClientCertificate cert) {
       m_cert = cert;
    }
    public virtual byte[] BinaryIssuer { get{return m_cert.BinaryIssuer;} }
    public virtual int CertEncoding { get{return m_cert.CertEncoding;} }
    //other methods
    //...
}

public class TestClass {
  [TestMethod]
  public void Test() {
      //we can pass null as constructor argument, since the mocked class will never use it and mock methods will be called instead
      var certMock = new Mock<HttpClientCertificate>(null);
      certMock.Setup(cert=>cert.BinaryIssuer).Returns(new byte[1]);
  }
}
```

In your code that uses `HttpClientCertificate` you instead use `HttpClientCertificateBase`, which you can instantiate like this - `new HttpClientCertificateBase(httpClientCertificateInstance)`. This way you are creating a test surface for you to plug in mock objects.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you need to specify constructor parameters when creating the mock of the HttpClientCertificate.

```
var certMock = new Mock<HttpClientCertificate>(ctorArgument);
```

The bad news is that the ctor for HttpClientCertificate is internal and takes in an HttpContext, so it probably won't work.

Comment: You can still make it work by using FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject()...it doesnt call constructor to call create an instance. Same way WCF creates instances of request obj.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to write more code to make the class "Testable" I suggest you use [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/typemock-isolator-product3), Unless specified otherwise it looks for the first c'tor available - public, internal or private and fake (mocks) it's parameters so you won't have to.

Creating the fake object is as simple as:

```
var fakeHttpClientCertificate = Isolate.Fake.Instance<HttpClientCertificate>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the [free Microsoft Moles framework](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/). It will allow you to replace any .NET method with your own delegate. Check out the link as it gives an example that is pretty easy to understand. I think you'll find it much nicer than adding layers of indirection to get `HttpClientCertificate` into a testable state.