# ASP.NET MVC 4 Unit Test - Is there a way to mock HttpClientCertificate with Moq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

My web app is using PKI authentication via a piv card. I grab the user's unique identifier information via HttpClientCertificate.Subject. The problem is that when I am unit testing, mock will not mock this class since it doesn't have a constructor. I tried following the advice on this thread:

[How to mock HttpClientCertificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634249/how-to-mock-httpclientcertificate)

but it looks like the way he sets it up is to inject the client certificate through the controller's constructor which I dont' want to do since the controller already has access to the client certificate. I'm assuming thats what he is implying since he is using some type of adapter pattern. Anyone got any better sugguestions?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you wrap it into your own object?

```
class MyHttpClientCertificate
{
    public MyHttpClientCertificate(HttpClientCertificate foo) { ... }

    internal MyHttpClientCertificate() { ... }
}
```

Comment: That would require me to inject the client certificate into my controller which I don't want to do since the controller already has access to it.

Comment: just override the property that the controller has with `new`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the code is using the Request object to get the certificate, but that's not easily unit testable.

What I would do is add a function delegate that, by default, will use the Request object to return the HttpClientCertificate, but will allow overriding the implementation.

For the controller, add this:

```
internal Func<HttpClientCertificate> HttpClientCertificateGetter = () => {
  return Request.ClientCertificate;
}
```

And in your Controller instead of using Request use HttpClientCertificateGetter.

Then in your unit test you mock the certificate and assign it to the getter function, like this:

```
var certMock = new Mock<HttpClientCertificate>();
HttpClientCertificate clientCertificate = certMock.Object;
requestMock.Setup(b => b.ClientCertificate).Returns(clientCertificate);
certMock.Setup(b => b.Certificate).Returns(new Byte[] { });

controller.HttpClientCertificateGetter = () => {certMock.Object};
```

Comment: I tried your approach but cannot get it to work. Apparently you cannot use moq to mock the httpclientcertificate because the class has no constructor.